# How to fill 56 comboBox with loop or something

Tags: c#, loops, combobox, fill

I have 56 comboBox in my program and I need to fill all of them with the same information. The fastes way that I found is creating a private function for fill the comboBox. And I put 56 times the same function.

But my question is... I can do a loop for fill this 56 comboBox?

Comment: To answer your question: Yes, you can do a loop to fill your comboboxes. The C# language provides several keywords allowing you to create loops, like `for`, `foreach`, `while`, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this question is about Windows Forms. The best way to do it is probably to have the similar naming convention for all `ComboBox` controls you're willing to fill with the same data. Fill them with items within for-loop, adding different suffix to the control you want to find before adding data.

```
// Lets say you have 56 ComboBox controls with names like : cbMyComboBox_1, cbMyComboBox_2, ..., cbMyComboBox_56
for (int i = 1; i <= 56; i++)
{
    ComboBox comboBox = (ComboBox)this.Controls.Find
        (string.Format("cbMyComboBox_{0}", i), true)[0];
    ComboBoxFill(comboBox);
}

private void ComboBoxFill(ComboBox comboBox)
{
    // Fill that ComboBox with data here
}
```

Comment: @Oriol Lopez No problem. Using Controls.Find method with searchAllChildren flag set to true guarantees you that control will be found even if it's nested within panel, groupBox or any other control.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can.

```
foreach (var c in Controls)
{
    if (c is ComboBox)
        ((ComboBox)c).Text = "I'm a combobox~";
}
```

Comment: I use your code but it doesn't work

       {
             foreach (var c in Controls)
            {           
                if (c is ComboBox) c=Fill(c);
            }
        }

Comment: @OriolLopez Would you put the `Fill()` method here?

Comment: Yes, but the parameter "c" don't recognized as ComboBox

Comment: @OriolLopez Yes, as for now, the variable `c` is still a `Control`, in order to use it as a `ComboBox`, you need to cast it.

Answer (score -2):

try adding the same class to all 56 combobox, and create a function to populate then like:
$(".class").html(value of the options);